# How do I use a Button multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I don't know if it is possible but I was wondering if a button in Java AWT or Swing could be used more than once? Bear with me because I am new to programming.

So I wanted this Choice box that presents the user with options.They select one and press the button continue.
Then the items of the choice are changed and I say `b=new Button("");` or `b.setText("")` and change the `Button` description and use it again for another function. I wish to read using `ActionListener`.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to realize some kind of questionnaire. Please read up on [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as it might be the correct layout manager for your situation. A CardLayout can be used to "swipe" from panel to panel on some user action (like a button click) and each card (read: new panel) can have it's own GUI components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You strive to write simple code. One aspect of simplicity: any component, class, object should be responsible for **one** thing (see [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

In your case: GUI elements typically do **one** job. In general, you do **not** reuse components like buttons.

Sure, what can make sense:

- that you dynamically add/remove GUI elements on a central container (like a panel)
- that you dynamically enable/disable buttons for example

But you should really not think about reusing individual button objects. Because that means that your button "logic" (that ActionListener) will need to know what "state" the overall application is currently into. And that is more of an anti-pattern.